# Is there a way to view Codebuild builds in a dashboard in Cloudwatch, like a Jenkins dashboard monitor?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

Due to some Jenkins slave agent issue we were experiencing, we're trying to run all our tests in AWS via Codebuild. However, is there a way to monitor all the Codebuild builds in a single dashboard, like a monitor dashboard in Jenkins?  I was looking everywhere for a solution but to no avail.  I'm mainly trying to setup a monitor that shows whether the last build for multiple test suites passed or failed. e.g. if i have 10 different builds, I'd like to see the last build status of those 10 builds in one dashboard.